# Disable Chrome "Save Card?" popup with Capybara

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, browser-automation

What argument or preference do you configure Chrome with, when using Capybara and Selenium, to disable this "Save card?" dialog?

[image: Save Card popup in Chrome browser]

```
browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Options.chrome
browser_options.add_preference <WHAT GOES HERE?>
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The preference for the "Save card?" behavior is `autofill.credit_card_enabled`.

To disable it:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Options.chrome

  # Disable "Save card?" popup:
  browser_options.add_preference :autofill, credit_card_enabled: false
  # This also works:
  # browser_options.add_preference 'autofill.credit_card_enabled', false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end
```

---

To discover the names of preferences like these in Chrome:

1. Set and save the preference to the value you desire in the UI in `chrome://settings`
2. Go to `chrome://version/` and note the "Profile Path"
3. Open the `Preferences` file found below the "Profile Path". This is a JSON file.
4. Search this file for a string that looks like it would correspond to the preference you set in step 1. For example `"autofill":{"credit_card_enabled":false,` is the string I found when researching this answer. You can derive the preference name and value from this, e.g. `autofill.credit_card_enabled=false`.